# Is it possible to use the full RevMob API in an HTML5 iOS app? (Using Cordova/Phonegap)

Tags: ios, html, cordova, revmob

I'm using Apache Cordova to build an html5 game.
I want to use RevMob, and I'm following this tutorial http://sdk.revmob.com/cordova#ios-setup

Everything works fine, but it appears that I have access to only two of the RevMob API calls.
I can only use fullscreen ads and ad popups.

I'm willing to use versions of the RevMob SDK different from the latest stable version.

Is there a way to enable the rest of the RevMob functionality in an HTML5 app?
E.g. "More Games", or "Banner Ad"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! They released version 0.4.0 which includes:

```
revmob.openAdLink();
```

Among other features as you can [see](http://sdk.revmob.com/cordova).